# Why ReactJS needs compilation

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Reactjs is consists of `.js` files and JavaScript doesn't compile as it's an interpreted language. Then why Reactjs need to be compiled? I read that it uses the JSX compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JSX includes markup syntax that isn't valid javascript. The JSX "compiler" translates the markup into vanilla javascript. You can see this yourself using the [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/):

JSX in:

```
const Test = () => <div>test</div>
```

Javascript out:

```js
"use strict";

var Test = function Test() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, "test");
};
```

There's also the matter of bundling, resolving imports, adding polyfills, etc.

Comment: supporting this ans for referring to babel repl

Answer (score 4):

It goes through a sort of minimization, and converts all that non-stock-javascript JSX code into regular Javascript. It's not making it any faster really, like compiling C to machine code, but it's converting it into Javascript that your browser can understand.

Comment: I'd argue that minifying the code actually makes load times _faster_

Comment: It makes it _smaller_ but it doesn't make it _run_ faster.

Comment: @jmm That is potentially true. Since the filesize would be smaller too, it's probably slightly better for data. As far as actual performance time I don't think it's any better or worse though. I'm not too familiar on the process of minifying, or how different browsers load external scripts.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to compile javascript to use react. Check out the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) for how to use it without.

However, there are certain components in declarative GUI systems like react that are verbose and cumbersome to write in a generic language. Thus, react provides a Javascript variant known as "JSX" that allows you to write XHTML right inside the javascript code. A browser does not know JSX since it was invented by the react team. Thus, react needs a way to transform the parts of fancy XML into generic Javacript your browser can understand.